# Finding a valley in a noisy data

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, logic, artificial-intelligence

```
Date        Time_GMTTime_IST    Current
11/15/2016  5:12:27 10:42:27    26.61
11/15/2016  5:12:28 10:42:28    42.27
11/15/2016  5:12:29 10:42:29    25.48
11/15/2016  5:12:30 10:42:30    24.24
11/15/2016  5:12:31 10:42:31    25.91
11/15/2016  5:12:32 10:42:32    27.75
11/15/2016  5:12:33 10:42:33    24.46
11/15/2016  5:12:34 10:42:34    24.32
11/15/2016  5:12:35 10:42:35    24.81
11/15/2016  5:12:36 10:42:36    27.36
11/15/2016  5:12:37 10:42:37    28.2
11/15/2016  5:12:38 10:42:38    28.29
11/15/2016  5:12:39 10:42:39    26.52
11/15/2016  5:12:40 10:42:40    32.58
11/15/2016  5:12:41 10:42:41    24.24
11/15/2016  5:12:42 10:42:42    24.36
11/15/2016  5:12:43 10:42:43    26.48
11/15/2016  5:12:44 10:42:44    28.76
11/15/2016  5:12:45 10:42:45    24.51
11/15/2016  5:12:46 10:42:46    23.93
11/15/2016  5:12:47 10:42:47    25.23
11/15/2016  5:12:48 10:42:48    27.9
11/15/2016  5:12:49 10:42:49    27.84
11/15/2016  5:12:50 10:42:50    27.31
11/15/2016  5:12:51 10:42:51    29.17
11/15/2016  5:12:52 10:42:52    24
11/15/2016  5:12:53 10:42:53    32.51
11/15/2016  5:12:54 10:42:54    26.63
11/15/2016  5:12:55 10:42:55    22.34
11/15/2016  5:12:56 10:42:56    29.14
11/15/2016  5:12:57 10:42:57    46.62
11/15/2016  5:12:58 10:42:58    48.85
11/15/2016  5:12:59 10:42:59    30.59
11/15/2016  5:13:00 10:43:00    30.68
11/15/2016  5:13:01 10:43:01    30.82
11/15/2016  5:13:02 10:43:02    31.64
11/15/2016  5:13:03 10:43:03    43.91
```

The above is a sample data, the data goes on for days.I have to find the depression in current as shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QT2ZL.png). If the current goes below 30 amps for a long time I have to detect that valley-like depression. I have been working on it for a while and I'm not able to think of any logic that can find the solution precicely. Any kind of suggestion is appreciated. A machine learning approach is also accepted.

Comment: I am not sure 100% what you are asking us to do. What do you mean by 'a long time'. Lets define long time as `n`. What I would do to start is : create greedy version: iterate over all collection if we are on `a_i` element check all (n) elements around it and if they are monotonically decreasing to `a_i` then you got yourself a valley. From greedy version (if it is too slow) you can try divide and conquer approach.

Comment: I did that and it worked for a predefined time frame. But in my problem, the long time starts from 15 minutes ie. 900 seconds to however long the drop may last for and that's why I'm stuck. @MaLiN2223

Answer (score 4):

You could just use a *moving window average* approach:

1. Select an appropriate window width (in your case, the delta between entries is one second each, so your chosen width will be in dimensions of seconds)
2. Iterate over your `currents` column and calculate the average of `currents` with respect to your chosen window width
3. Check when it drops below a threshold or raises above it, depending on its prior state

With your example data, this may look like the following. In this plot, your original `currents` data is depicted as a blue dotted line, the moving average is the thick green line and state changes are marked as red vertical lines.

[image: Rolling window and state changes]

The code I used to generate that image is:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

c = [26.61, 42.27, 25.48, 24.24, 25.91, 27.75, 24.46, 24.32, 24.81, 27.36, 28.2, 28.29, 26.52, 32.58, 24.24, 24.36, 26.48, 28.76, 24.51, 23.93, 25.23, 27.9, 27.84, 27.31, 29.17, 24, 32.51, 26.63, 22.34, 29.14, 46.62, 48.85, 30.59, 30.68, 30.82, 31.64, 43.91]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Choose window width and threshold
    window = 5
    thres = 27.0

    # Iterate and collect state changes with regard to previous state
    changes = []
    rolling = [None] * window
    old_state = None
    for i in range(window, len(c) - 1):
        slc = c[i - window:i + 1]
        mean = sum(slc) / float(len(slc))
        state = 'good' if mean > thres else 'bad'

        rolling.append(mean)
        if not old_state or old_state != state:
            print('Changed to {:>4s} at position {:>3d} ({:5.3f})'.format(state, i, mean))
            changes.append((i, state))
            old_state = state

    # Plot results and state changes
    plt.figure(frameon=False, figsize=(10, 8))
    currents, = plt.plot(c, ls='--', label='Current')
    rollwndw, = plt.plot(rolling, lw=2, label='Rolling Mean')
    plt.axhline(thres, xmin=.0, xmax=1.0, c='grey', ls='-')
    plt.text(40, thres, 'Threshold: {:.1f}'.format(thres), horizontalalignment='right')
    for c, s in changes:
        plt.axvline(c, ymin=.0, ymax=.7, c='red', ls='-')
        plt.text(c, 41.5, s, color='red', rotation=90, verticalalignment='bottom')
    plt.legend(handles=[currents, rollwndw], fontsize=11)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.savefig('local/plot.png', dpi=72, bbox_inches='tight')
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try to find valleys using similar idea, but using `numpy` convolution:

1. Pick a window and compute smoothed data e.g., with MA (moving average) using convolution.
2. Compute the residual from the original data and the smoothed data.
3. Valley points are the consecutive points where residual values are small.

   ```
   import numpy as np
   Import pandas as pd # read data in data frame df
   w_sz = 3 # window size
   ma = np.convolve(df.Current, np.ones(w_sz)/w_sz, mode='same')
   resid = df.Current - ma
   threshold = 1 #0.1
   prob_val = np.where(abs(resid)<=threshold)
   val_indices = np.where(np.diff(prob_val) != 1)[1]+1 
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   plt.plot(df.Current)
   plt.plot(ma)
   plt.plot(resid)
   plt.axhline(0)
   plt.plot(val_indices, np.zeros(len(val_indices)), 'o', color='red')
   plt.legend(['Current', 'MA-smoothed', 'Residual'], loc='upper center');
   plt.show()
   ```

[image]
There are 3 valleys shown in the figure, between each 2 consecutive red points. It seems there is only one red point for the first valley, but actually there are two consecutive points and the length of the valley is one. We can filter out small length valleys too.

Comment: Isn't this a forward-looking approach? So the index for a valley seems shifted a bit when comparing red markers to original `Current` data (or they indicate the first index of moving average).

Comment: @jbndlr yes kind off, since moving average works on a window, on the boundaries of the window, there will be some irregularities (e.g., the MA will stabilize slightly after the data stabilizes), but we can change the behavior according to our requirement either by changing the `mode` argument in `convolution` or by using smaller windows or finally doing some post-processing after the indices are returned). But I think this shift may make some sense since we are not immediately reacting to the stabilization in data values, rather waiting sometime to get more confident about the stabilization.

Comment: This shift will help us in getting rid of small length valleys, since it will make them still smaller.

Comment: I like the approach, but somehow I feel that this solution has a deviation from the intended result. You apply a smoothing-like convolution and compare the residuals, which essentially means that your threshold is not fixed, doesn't it? Just trying to deeper follow your approach..

Comment: @ jbndlr convolution is just a smarter approach for computing moving average. Finding right threshold is a different problem altogether. For the points in the valley the approach will imply the consecutive points for which the residual values are small. Now threshold defines what we consider as small residual, it may have numeric value as 0.1 or 1 or 10 depending on the magnitude of the data value and the precision required.

Comment: I know the concept of residuals, I meant to point out that the comparison against a non-fixed threshold does not allow to compare the `Current` value against a desired value, e.g. `30`. Please elaborate more on this if I got you wrong.

Comment: I am not sure i understood you, what do you mean by a `non-fixed threshold`? The threshold we are fixing a-priori for a fixed dataset (assuming offline processing), but it's a parameter that's may change for different daatasets and requirement. In case of streaming / online data, we can learn the threshold over time, if we don't know a good one, or decide to keep it fixed as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135361/discussion-between-jbndlr-and-sandipan-dey).